# NSLocale - get all available languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there a way to get all available languages on the iphone just like in the settings app?

can't find a method in NSLocales Class Reference.

thanks!

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/80699/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-26%20um%2019.45.49.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/80699/Bildschirmfoto%202010-07-26%20um%2019.45.49.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is `[NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]`…

EDIT: what do you mean by “I need the local identifiers”? Do you mean the NSLocale identifiers or the localized language names?
I fear the latter is not possible.

Comment: i need exactly the same thing as in the settings "app". i want to store the local identifier to a string and work with it at some other time with `initWithLocaleIdentifier`. i will then run several things, using Numberformatter, dateformatter and so on

Comment: I’m pretty sure [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers] yields exactly the list you need but I’m also pretty sure it’s not possible to construct human-readable names from the locale identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

NSLocale displayNameForKey:value: is your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

`[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` will get you a list of codes like this, which you can translate yourself:

```
en,
fr,
de,
ja,
nl,
it,
es,
```

Comment: are this "all" languages, and whant means "translate myself"? i need the local identifier.

Comment: You need to translate "en" into "English" and so on.